# Adding / after fifth character in React js using formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Hey I am pretty new in React js and I want to know how can I solve this problem **how to add /  after the fifth character**. Is there a way how to do this with formik or any way in general ?

```
number: Yup.string()
    .min(11, "Minimum 11 characters")
    .max(11, "Maximum 5 characters")
    .required("This field is required"),
    // add dash after fifth character
```

Thank you for every answer.
I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use yups [`transform`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematransformcurrentvalue-any-originalvalue-any--any-schema) method to add the dash.

Something like:

```js
number: Yup.string()
    .transform((value) => value.slice(0, 5) + "-" + value.slice(5))
    .min(11, "Minimum 11 characters")
    .max(11, "Maximum 5 characters")
    .required("This field is required"),
```

Remember that transformations are run before validations so you most likely want to change the limits on the `min` and `max`

Comment: Hello , thanks for the answer but I really struggle to implement it what should i put in txt1 value ? should i put value.number ?

Comment: No you should use `value.slice(5)` since you want the end of the value you are transforming. I edited the example to illustrate it.